# HTML/CSS Rounded Rectangles?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to create a rectangle with rounded edges without using an image? For example:

[image: Rounded Edges]

Thank you.

Comment: You may find this site helpful: http://border-radius.com/

Comment: Used that but didn't make corners rounded.

Comment: what browser are you using? I doubt it will work in IE. May not work in older versions of some other browsers as well.

Comment: I am using Google Chrome

Comment: Does not seem like you're actually making an effort yourself. Sorry.

Comment: please update your question with your relevant screen shots of your code, or even post your code as it is easier for other users to see.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a good tutorial to understand rounded border for any div:

http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/

Or you can round a border of a certain div like this:

```
#div1 {
-moz-border-radius: 15px; //for mozilla support
-webkit-border-radius: 15px; //for chrome support
border-radius: 15px;
}
```

in a nut shell:

You can combine these as you like. `-webkit-`... will only be recognized by WebKit browsers (Chrome, Safari), `-moz-`... will only be recognized by Mozilla-based browsers (Firefox.)

**EDIT:**

You can only apply border-radius to td, not tr or table. I've gotten around this for rounded corner tables by using these styles:

```
table { border-collapse: separate; }
td { border: solid 1px #000; }
tr:first-child td:first-child { -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 15px; }
tr:first-child td:last-child { -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 15px; }
tr:last-child td:first-child { -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 15px; }
tr:last-child td:last-child { -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 15px; }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I used that but it changed nothing. :\

Comment: and html? can you attach screenshot of your result.

Comment: HTML: http://screensnapr.com/v/bnYlV2.png
RESULT: http://screensnapr.com/v/DfXX5I.png

Comment: Ok no need for screenshots. just add -webkit-border-radius: 15px; in css. It will work.

Comment: It is not working because you are trying to put it on a tr. which is not possible. See my edited answer. I've again edited it for you.

Comment: It was because of what you said, i was putting it on a <tr> Now i just need to find out how to round only the top left and top right corners, could you help me with that?

Comment: Yes of course, use -webkit-border-top-left-radius for top left and -webkit-border-top-right-radius for top right.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this, with your own customizations:

HTML

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="top">Settings</div>
    This is some text. It is part of an example of rounded borders in css. It is two lines long by now, I suppose.
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.outer{
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #8AF;
    padding: 0px 20px;
}

div.outer .top{
    margin: 0px -20px;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    background-color: #8AF;
    color: #000;
}
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/ksPeY/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the css property `border-radius`.

However it is not supported on older browser.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some examples and also browser support info.

border-*-*-radius: [  | <%> ] [  | <%> ]?

```
#example1 {
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px;
height: 150px;
Width:150px;
}
```

Real World Example: This should show a grey box with rounded corders in most browsers except IE < 7

HTML

```
<div id="RoundCorners">

</div>
```

CSS

```
#RoundCorners
{
   border-radius: 15px;
   moz-border-radius: 15px; //If using Firefox
   background-color: #333;
}
```

At present Opera (version 10.5 onward), Safari (version 5 onward) and Chrome (version 5 onward) all support the individual border-*-radius properties and the border-radius shorthand property as natively defined in the current W3C Specification (although there are still outstanding bugs on issues such as border style transitions, using percentages for lengths, etc.).

Mozilla Firefox (version 1.0 onward) supports border-radius with the -moz- prefix, although there are some discrepancies between the Mozilla implementation and the current W3C specification (see below).

Update:Recent Firefox nightly versions support border-radius without the -moz- prefix.

Safari and Chrome (and other webkit based browsers) have supported border-radius with the -webkit- prefix since version 3 (no longer needed from version 5 onward), although again with some discrepancies from the current specification (see this article for further details of how older versions of Webkit handle border-radius).

Even Microsoft have promised, and demonstrated in their recent preview release, support for border-radius from Internet Explorer 9 onward (without prefix).

Comment: I used that, but it doesn't round the corners.

Comment: @Duncan Palmer  Which browser are you using to test? also, do you want to post your CSS ?

Comment: Google Chrome and i am using this:


#test{
background: #000000;
border-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
}

Comment: @Duncan Palmer I have added another example including the basix HTML.. Hpefully this helps you out. This is testing and definately works. Your example didn't have any H or W.

Answer (score 0):

Make a rectangle clip and place a rectangle with thick and round border over it.